# Passing keyword arguments to a class method decorator

Tags: python, decorator

I have a class that has an output() method which returns a matplotlib Figure instance. I have a decorator I wrote that takes that fig instance and turns it into a Django response object.

My decorator looks like this:

```
class plot_svg(object):
    def __init__(self, view):
        self.view = view

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print args, kwargs
        fig = self.view(*args, **kwargs)
        canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
        response=HttpResponse(content_type='image/svg+xml')
        canvas.print_svg(response)
        return response
```

and this is how it was being used:

```
def as_avg(self):
    return plot_svg(self.output)()
```

The only reason I has it that way instead of using the "@" syntax is because when I do it with the "@":

```
@plot_svg
def as_svg(self):
    return self.output()
```

I get this error:

```
as_svg() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

I'm trying to 'fix' this by putting it in the "@" syntax but I can't figure out how to get it working. I'm thinking it has something to do with `self` not getting passed where it's supposed to...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right: when you decorate with a class, instead of with a function, you have to make it a descriptor (give it a `__get__` method, at least) to get the "automatic self".  Simplest is to decorate with a function instead:

```
def plot_svg(view):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print args, kwargs
        fig = view(*args, **kwargs)
        canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/svg+xml')
        canvas.print_svg(response)
        return response

    return wrapper
```

Background: the reason functions "become methods" (when defined in a class and accessed on an instance thereof by attribute-get notation), in other words, the reason such functions can get their automatic `self` is that they're descriptors -- the function type has a `__get__`.

A class doesn't have a `__get__` method -- unless you explicitly add one.  So why not just decorate with a function instead, as in the above example?  This way you get the nice `__get__` of functions automatically -- and as you see the nested function "lexical closure" property doesn't pose any problem at all (indeed, it simplifies things -- the nested function calls `view`, not `self.view` which might be rather confusing if `self` could mean either an instance of your decorator class OR an instance of the class *whose method you're decorating*...!-).

Comment: I'm confused by your answer.  I had thought the substitution was equivalent to the expected lexical substitution.  So:

     @plot_svg(view=some_view)
     def some_func(some_args): ...

     -> (minus intermediate variables/bindings)
     def some_func(some_args): ...
     a_plot_instance = plot_svg.__init__(view=some_view)
     some_func = a_plot_instance.__call__(some_args)

Can you clarify?  And I hate lack of comment formatting.

Comment: @charles.merriam: there **is** comment formatting. Use \*\* for **bold**, \* for *italics*, backticks (\`) for `code`, etc... You may need to use a backslash now and then...

Comment: I'm confused by your answer. I had thought the substitution was equivalent to the expected lexical substitution. So: `@plot_svg(view=some_view) `\n
`def some_func(some_args): ... `\n
-> (minus intermediate variables/bindings) \n
`def some_func(some_args): ... `\n
`a_plot_instance = plot_svg.__init__(view=some_view) `\n
`some_func = a_plot_instance.__call__(some_args)`\n
 Can you clarify?

Comment: @charles.merriam: If you don't start your comment with @Alex Martelli he will not be notified automatically and it's possible that he does not revisit the question then.

Comment: @ChristopheD, I do get notified anyway on comments to my answers -- you may have "replied to my comments" in mind.

Comment: @charles.merriam, **your class is not a descriptor unless it defines `__get__`**, so "substitution was equivalent" makes no sense; a **function** is always a descriptor, a class instance not always, and I can't clarify any further!  Study descriptors at http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm -- or just use the solution I suggest, which is a function, thus a descriptor, and therefore works by getting the "automatic `self`" arg.

Answer (score 1):

OK, there seem to be a couple of issues.

First, some syntax.  You are getting the "takes exactly one argument" error because
your decorator, @plot_svg, is expecting one parameter (a view).  There are other syntax errors as well.

Second, and more importantly, you want to write a function instead of a decorator.  A decorator destroys your access to one concept and only gives you access to the combined
concept.  You just want a new function like this:

```
def as_svg(an_object):
    return django_response(an_object.output())
```

Alternately, I misunderstand your question from having a little too little code example.